# XMLEncoder dont write file properly

Tags: java, xml, xmlencoder

I have a method that should write object to XML file

```
public void save(OutputStream os) {
    XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
    e.writeObject(this);
    e.flush();
    e.close();
}
```

This class have 4 fields

```
final static public String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
final public static String DEF_FILE_NAME = "security.conf";
private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
private String logKey;
```

and many methods, one of methods is `save(OutputStream os)` presented above.

But XMLEncoder write only this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_80" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
</java>
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Guess `this` is the `java.beans.XMLDecoder` and not the java object you want serialize to XML.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem... and note that you don't have any Javascript, so don't try to put things as Javascript snippets.

Comment: the class that has the save function probably extends or implements XMLDecoder

Comment: All program is too big to show here. this - object that don't implement and extend anything (except Object of course)

Comment: Is your class a JavaBean?

Comment: If You are asking about getters and setters then yes

Comment: The [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) documentation says *the XMLEncoder class is exclusively designed for the purpose of archiving graphs of JavaBeans as textual representations of their public properties.*

Comment: How to make my class as JavaBean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it. Problem was in constructor. Class must have public constructor with no parameters.